# HTML5 video not autoplaying in safari for React

Tags: reactjs, safari, html5-video

I've seen similar questions to this but none specifically what I am doing. I am autoplaying a video in the background on a page in React that is as follows:

```
const VideoProps: DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement> = {
  autoPlay: true,
  muted: true,
  loop: true,
  playsInline: true,
};

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(true);
  const initialMount = useInitialMount();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialMount) return;

    if (play) {
      (document.getElementById('intro_video') as HTMLVideoElement).play();
    } else {
      (document.getElementById('intro_video') as HTMLVideoElement).pause();
    }
  }, [play]);

  return (
    <>
      <video {...VideoProps} id={'intro_video'}>
        <source src="/videos/intro_mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <ActionIcon
        style={{ bottom: 2.5, right: 2.5, position: 'fixed' }}
        size={'xl'}
        onClick={() => setPlay(!play)}
      >
        {play ? (
          <IconPlayerPause />
        ) : (
          <IconPlayerPlay />
        )}
      </ActionIcon>
    </>
  );
};

IndexPage.displayName = 'IndexPage';

export default IndexPage;
```

The video autoplays correctly on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari on desktop. The following play icon appears instead of the video autoplaying[image]

Not sure why this is happening. All other suggestions say that adding `playsInline` should be the fix.

Update: Not working on desktop but the non auto play on IOS was due to the device being in low battery mode.